# Problem "Service Unavailable" with CUPS C API IPP request

Tags: c, linux, cups

i'm trying to use CUPS C Api in order to control a printer from a C program.
I've read the docs but i'm not able to get information from printer using IPP calls.
My not-working code is:

```
request = ippNewRequest(CUPS_GET_PRINTERS);
ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_URI, "printer-uri", NULL, "ipp://EPSON%20XP-3150%20Series%20(USB)._ipp._tcp.local/");
ippAddStrings(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_KEYWORD, "requested-attributes", 
                    sizeof(requested_attributes)/sizeof(requested_attributes[0]), NULL, requested_attributes);
ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_NAME, "requesting-user-name", NULL, cupsUser());

response = cupsDoRequest(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, request, resource);

printf("%d - %s\n", cupsLastError(), cupsLastErrorString() );
```

The output of the program is always the same:

```
1282 - Unknown
```

I watch from the CUPS source code that 1282 (0x502) stands for SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE. I tried to change printer URI using ipp://localhost but it doesn't work at all.

If i use the tool lpstat i have the results i need (printer warnigs and printer status).

```
lpstat -l -p EPSON_XP_3150_Series_USB_
```

and it works like a charm. What is my error? I saw in the lpstat.c source code from github but it seems to do like my code but it works.

Thanks :)

Comment: Your example of using `lpstat` does not match what you have in your code. In your code you have %20 (a space) in the lptstat command line you use underscores. Your code also has parentheses around USB.

Answer (score 0):

Jim Rhodes, thanks for your help.
I've modified my test code in order to get URI from CUPS Api.

```
num_printers = cupsGetDests(&printers);
printer = &printers[0];
printer_uri = cupsGetOption("device-uri", printer->num_options, printer->options);

printf("printer uri: %s\n", printer_uri);

//request
request = ippNewRequest(CUPS_GET_PRINTERS);
ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_URI, "printer-uri", NULL, printer_uri);
ippAddStrings(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_KEYWORD, "requested-attributes", 
                    sizeof(requested_attributes)/sizeof(requested_attributes[0]), NULL, requested_attributes);
ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_NAME, "requesting-user-name", NULL, cupsUser());

response = cupsDoRequest(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, request, resource);

printf("%d - %s\n", cupsLastError(), cupsLastErrorString() );
```

I have no more the 0x502 error but it returns NULL on response...

Comment: i changed "resource" with "/" and it worked...